# Creating a input field dynamically using other input values

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a HTML form with several input fields and a very special input field named as "**custom_1**".

When submitting the form (on or before), all values in other input fields should be converted to a JSON object and set as the value of **custom_1**

If the values are predefined, following code can do what I expect.

```
 <?php
$json = array(
    'first_name' => 1,
    'last_name' => 1,
    'gender' => 1,
    'email' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
    'phone' => 345345431,
    'telephone' => '035w34538',
    'address' => 1,
    'country' => 1,
    'city' => 1,
    'postal_code' => 1,
    'dob' => '3333-03-03',
    'nic' => '333333333V',
    'course_provider' => 1,
    'course' => 1,
    'postal_code' => 10012
);

$custom_values = base64_encode(json_encode($json));
?>

<input type="hidden" name="custom_1" value="<?php echo $custom_values; ?>">
```

But the problem is, this array should be created and assign the value to the **custom_1** field on form submit. That means the values are not predefined and they should be taken from other input fields in the form.

> Submitting form and getting individual post parameters is not what I expect. All parameters should be taken into the **custom_1** as explained above.

Comment: Have you tried anything? HTML form, onSubmit handler, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It is simple using jquery (ofcourse you can use every other library as well)

Here is a quick code snippet:

https://codepen.io/YannickFricke/pen/EGwYgy

The relevant part happens here:
We get an array of objects from jQuery. We need to iterate over them, to get the name of the serialized input fields and their current values.

Then we save them in a object which will be later decoded as JSON and then decoded as base64 value.

```
let serializedData = $(this).serializeArray();
let myData = {};
serializedData.forEach(function(element) {
    // We dont want to serialize the value of the "custom_1" input
    if (element.name === 'custom_1') {
      return;
    }

    // Set the data
    myData[element.name] = element.value;
});
```

After that part we encode the object as json and encode it as base64 string.

Then the base64 encoded string is set as value in the "custom_1" input field.